# exec: "code": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: visual-studio-code, onflow-cadence

I am trying to download a VSCode extension in order to be able to use cadence in VSCode, but when I type:

```
flow version
```

and then:

```
flow cadence install-vscode-extension
```

into the command line, I keep getting this error: `exec: "code": executable file not found in $PATH`. What executable file am I supposed to have in order to download this extension?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First do this in VS Code:

Once installed, open Visual Studio Code, open the command palette (press Shift+Command+P on macOS and Shift+Ctrl+P on Linux/Windows), then search for Install code command and press enter.

and then:

flow cadence install-vscode-extension

https://github.com/onflow/flow/blob/master/docs/vscode-extension.md#cadence-visual-studio-code-extension